# Diverging limits equating to infinity and negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

In trying to determine whether $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{x}{x-2}=\infty$. I've found that the limit diverges and equates to both infinity and negative infinity. Does this mean that the limit does equal infinity or that it does not? What does a diverging limit mean?

Comment: I think this related Math StackExchange post will be helpful. It's not the same function, but it explains a bit *why* a limit doesn't exist if the right- and left-hand limits are not the same.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23649/limit-approaches-infinity-on-one-side-and-negative-infinity-on-other-side?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The convention is as follows, except for when it isn't.

- $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=\infty$ means that for all $M$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $y\in (2-\delta,2+\delta)\setminus \{2\}$, $f(y)>M$. This is not the case for $f(x)=\frac x{x-2}$.
- $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=-\infty$ means that for all $M$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $y\in (2-\delta,2+\delta)\setminus \{2\}$, $f(y)<M$. This is not the case for $f(x)=\frac x{x-2}$.

It is true that $\lim_{x\to 2}\left\lvert \frac x{x-2}\right\rvert=\infty$, for the aforementioned reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In order for $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x}{x-2}\ $ to exist [i.e. for the limit to converge], both: $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x}{x-2}\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{x}{x-2}\ $ must exist and be equal to the same finite real number. Else the limit does not converge, i.e. the limit diverges. If they both "equal $\ +\infty\ $", certainly it is true that the limit diverges (since $\ +\infty\ $ is not a finite real number), so we might say that the limit is "equal to $\ +\infty\ $", but this is usually considered an abuse of notation.